# Linear equations for constructing molecules with covalent bonds

Tags: bond, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, molecules

(By training I am a math-guy and my knowledge of chemistry is restricted to school level)

I have read a little bit about the electron spheres and sub-spheres, the Aufbau principle and covalent bonds from Wikipedia.

Is it possible to derive theoretically molecules based on covalent bonds using linear equations? I am asking this because I did some computations in Sagemath:

For instance:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&6\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\text{Free module of degree 3 and rank 2 over Integer Ring Echelon basis matrix:}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
3&1&-1\\
0&2&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\ce{3H} & + & \ce N & -& \ce{Cr}\\
& + & \ce{2N} & - & \ce{Cr}\\
\end{array}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&7\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\text{Free module of degree 3 and rank 2 over Integer Ring Echelon basis matrix:}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&-1\\
0&7&-3\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\ce{H} & + & \ce {2N} & -& \ce{V}\\
& + & \ce{7N} & - & \ce{3V}\\
\end{array}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
8&1&3\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\text{Free module of degree 3 and rank 2 over Integer Ring Echelon basis matrix:}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&-3\\
0&3&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\ce{Ti} & + & \ce H & -& \ce{3N}\\
& + & \ce{3H} & - & \ce{N}\\
\end{array}\\
$$

More such examples in [Sagemath-Cell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzdmFtPG0sWhd_9K2rww7ZN4-n7xTo-UkJCYA4QhJnLiWWhBjfQ4Ju6247RUf77rFXVBjsjMpOHmYdBUVSurvr2ruq1l6u8SouWrK1naTca56qvwkb5kE0mJZrDVm49ttXdvFC5ymeqSGf3Wcuxzvcd0_u43Zujd9RolPOiysbXLxDzuQXW_qOVWxr5c8x2YzxN10CN89sKII2w3E7L7TweOD8Na_CBTo8Pd9LtNRT-8gUTrfpmkOmyHhG_0u3moshnVWvd6eSd504HY_XCmOOwIr-pnK6azL9myGr_ER_drsrv2AbjZP8vqnrIZpsBjcY4u1Pp8u4mXbZmFl5Eu87iTs1Uv--YT_wrsmpZzNS686y7kD9e0Ui3_92Stpalttf1_drqwJNs1ppM2r_ar7NNxG66WGSzMR4OD5zR_suaNyOySZm9NWdncL2JCLIZ-LKOyes7q_PAS-7tpDcZTka_9Gfql75u7zuj3aDT51MsabLTt0TP7EBP3emvM8EUa2lyo2rtl3SeXtPBmP3tVMyO93c3fPg0-uktL_chbrM9HeiqlR_YbWqr9YhG4-1QOqFR461Q22EYYvkGvBZW2TBivM-qs3Q9IOY_UyRqy2lb0KXl_F8ps1Fr6W6-nI2RyVEKyM_rVP23hNp8VWrzB1Jtvi2gWqvNt95C8_vX0PwfybX5I71ia5fbCtjI0HwxvBpzneNBvV27EnhrUh3D_JdPF1iBWqSzcVoq_FuM4e-LDHkuxt0iS8fXt-WqtbfIinzOr6frKr2ZZNfZJJtms6rs4umeVWaL_p61x6-GBXdlkQ2He--q-TS_PV9Ob7ICDwfP05v5ZG-Eb9DFhGL7Q7ZHSE_9YfeUYymnp1xLuT3lWcrrKd9Sfk8Flgp6KrRU2FORpaKeii0V91RiqQSzbEzjbE7HfAcABwQHCAcMBxAHFAcYBxwHIAckBygHLAcwBzQHOAc8FzwXPBc8l_kwIfBc8FzwXPBc8FzwXPBc8FzwXPBc8FzwXPBc8FzwPPA88DzwPPA88DyukEsEzwPPA88DzwPPA88DzwPPA88DzwPPA88DzwfPB88HzwfPB88HzwfP555x08DzwfPB88HzwfPB88HzwfPB88HzwQvAC8ALwAvAC8ALwAvAC8ALwAv4FvgawAvAC8ALwAvAC8ALwAvAC8ALwQvBC8ELwQvBC8ELwQvBC8ELwQvBC_le-WLBC8ELwQvBC8ELwQvBi8CLwIvAi8CLwIvAi8CLwIvAi8CLwIvAi8CLqBRKBbwIvAi8CLwIvBi8GLwYvBi8GLwYvBi8GLwYvBi8GLwYvBi8GLwYvJjao_jAi8GLwUvAS8BLwEvAS8BLwEvAS8BLwEvAS8BLwEvAS8BLwEvAS8BLqGbKWetZC5qKtilpm5q2KWqbqrYpa5u6tilsm8q2KW2b2rYpbpvqtilvm_q2KXCbCrcpcZsxdNGYqtFlwxi6cHTl6NLRtaOLR1ePLh9dP7qAdAXpEtI15MTfLCWmzOtqlmPR9SzHmeiSltNcdFXLe_b4bIgubTkUXdxyLrq85bPoApcj0SUu55zAdOU8FVPmcnYvptDl3URMqcuAEZiuXIipdhmIKXc51KNIf1eIKXn5TUzNyyGxrHoZ3Iqpe7kijJUvfxNT-nLImSx-OZuJKX850svTEeZiLEDO9VRGOFyKsQH5whk0AvnEYLQC-cS5nl5DKcYOZKD79O4wGi1BftMtxri8EWMLMtB9jPG7GGeQL-zy9TZxmK-3iUnRH-SKK6NDyCWTokfI5YMYl5CLsRifkHfcWDqFHOo-hjhh8nQLGbAV6J1ijEDvFFOmZ8iJGNOQf-guhjjkymgc8p7rpnXIqW7pEHocQ1ww-UC_bYalhcjFVIyJyEC3GOIjk6eRyCc9jjGumArNRD48i7ETOebCaSjykWRailxpCmP8zhm0FTklL9JCvRNjLXLF_Ggu8ncx7iKXTJT-Ip-5IDqMnBBMj5GLSozLyDuNY4hj7iOdRq4oPXqNXDAs3UbeUyL0G7lgonQcfCeK8Ry55C7TdeSIMeg7csmkYh2Db5LeI1d8f4neKj6l_8hfxRiQnC_EWJBcMKlEh-AOJLrmdIsh3j-JsSI55A7QjOQjF0k7kqOp1H4kZ2OpDUnO51I7kpzqcrK1sO6k9iT5cCO1KclAV6qtQz1IbUtyXErtS3JWSW1M8qFUUluTXN6bNuMdzkxbr0tDdMEf6aLWFX92K7VDyelKaouSKx1Fl_3ne_n2jQcQc775kFbpUZFOs-5dMZ9e6-s3DiftRn0UXUzajbI0Z319Bx-vrfWah9BJXvJxN6-yoph_LVvt-iya4gah1uvvjj_mTFg-T-uHm8PQ9oE8nVkYYA5nVeVYpWONHYzfvq2k5rpiDomO9cjnGKs_f0XbUc1svWi5nUXeOflzK3f2H522GW6CIIIFyNipj7Hl5orQGjtWnQGOceXWDxtliStsY1y-_D6Be4S-9OgLT33LqddQvpxfy6E9-lPf3rkusI-TxmX3KXvGnu3eFcblkCNGm5TKH11uNoP5csrR5oWNS3PdbjQGeLD5XcRxcFWofxapmMBgeVNmVdkavF78eMMpq_avffc1zhkYrWlaFfm6NVxlt9W84JiRhVj3_S9f2q8JmvBnrx2rFSbXc4artMAGl8N8hJTbQ3e09ZPOFvdfcN0iv3-orp-yYpZNWlvhOHvF2XV234_s3qRlTlF2VqvdfTPkVfufVfOIOA==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

The example $\ce{3H} +  \ce N  - \ce{Cr}$ would correspond to a hypothetical molecule $\ce{CrH3N}$ (which I was able to find at [pubchem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/57466644)).

My questions are:

1. How do I search online for such molecules if they exist or not? Is
   there a standard way in specifying short molecule formulas?
2. Suppose I derive some equations for such hypothetical molecules
   based on linear equations of covalent bonds. Is there any chemical
   reason why these molecules might exist or not?